# Lua: Can Return statements be used in a ternary conditional statement?

Tags: lua, conditional-operator

I'm looking to improve my code, reducing if statements when possible. In this case I made a basic function to check a table for a known value, but lua is throwing an error when I tried to replace the if statement with a ternary conditional. Is there a way to include a return statement in a ternary conditional? The issue seems to be lua's requirement that return only be in the last statement of the block.
Reference/Ideal code,throws error:

> Console:4: syntax error near 'and'"

```
    --local method, search list for term, return position (or nil if not present)
    for i,v in pairs(self) do
        (v == query) and (return i);
    end
    return nil
end
```

Rewritten in case interpreter is confused about where statement ends causes same error:
`(v == query) and (do return i end);`
and [the manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.3.4) suggests this for when return isn't the last statement of a block

> **The return statement can only be written as the last statement of a block.** If it is really necessary to return in the middle of a block, then an explicit inner block can be used, as in the idiom **do return end**, because now return is the last statement in its (inner) block.

and yes, testing by using if-branch works fine:

```
find = function(self,query)
    --local method, search list for term, return position (or nil if not present)
    for i,v in pairs(self) do
        --(v == query) and (return i)
        if (v == query) then
            return i
        end
    end
    return nil
end
test = {"lime","grape","kiwi"}
find(test,"kiwi")
```

> 3

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing in Lua as a "ternary conditional statement". This: `(v == query) and (return i)` is an *expression* (or it's trying to be). The rules of the lua `and` expression allows you to use this as a form of ternary conditional *expression*. But the two parts of it must be expressions.

A return statement, as the name suggests, is not an *expression*. Therefore, it cannot go into the middle of an expression.

You'll have to do this with a regular `if` statement.

Comment: And you *should* do this with a regular `if` statement for readability alone, even in languages that might allow using `&&` / `and`.